# Search by attribute value (Orion NGSIv2)

Tags: fiware-orion

I was wondering if there is a way to search by attributes values which are inside an attribute already (not metadata). So let's say I have the following entity in Orion:

```
{   
    id: NJ8sE0r90,
    type: Review,
    commentCount: 12,
    aggregateRating: { 
        ratingValue: 1, 
        reviewCount: 73 
    }
}
```

I can search by first level attribute doing:

```
GET /v2/entities?q=commentCount>=10
```

But, is there a way (or will be) to search by `ratingValue` or `reviewCount`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is not yet available in Orion 0.24.0 (last version at the time of writting this answer) but it has been considered within the NGSIv2 scope and will be eventually implemented. You can monitor the status of [the following issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1156) at Orion repository so you can get aware when it gets implemented.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We will keep an eye on it :)